# Diet Plan- Eating Time Matters?

Tags: diet, gym, cutting

I got a shredding diet plan from a professional, and he advises that i should Eat every 2-3 hours, Does it really matter what time i eat as long as I eat what i am suppose to?

Comment: Before deciding whether you should or shouldn’t, you should really consider the purpose behind the plan’s suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[Eating more often does not matter for weight loss.](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diet-and-weight-loss/eating-frequency-and-weight-loss)

Also [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4033492/) states:

> Eating three to six meals per day with a meal containing 0.4-0.5 g/kg bodyweight of protein prior and subsequent to resistance training likely maximizes any theoretical benefits of nutrient timing and frequency. However, alterations in nutrient timing and frequency appear to have little effect on fat loss or lean mass retention.

It is a myth that has been debunked many times.

So from a physical standpoint, it won't make any difference. The biggest thing to worry about is eating at a slight caloric deficit to promote weightloss and high quality foods to promote energy and muscle retention.

So, if eating 2-3 hours a day helps with that, then by all means, do it. Some people feel hungrier when they eat less frequently and it motivates them to overeat when they finally get a meal. Eating every 2-3 hours *might* make them feel more satiated throughout the day which helps with consistency. It's always best to eat at a frequency that allows consistency which means that it has to fit around your lifestyle.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to follow your diet plan and eat every 2-3 hours as your body will have enough time digesting meals and have enough energy supply during your day.

Getting shredded is very hard as you try to lose fat around the muscle without loosing the muscle mass. 
Follow the instructions given by your dietitian, go the gym and workout regularly will get you closer to reach your goals.